Change color of svg icon through powerpoint web add-in
I'm developing a PowerPoint web add-in using Office.js and am having difficulty changing the color of an icon inserted into a slide. The icon is in SVG format, but I can't access the required properties of the SVG icon object to modify its color.
Any help or related post will be helpful.
We tried using below code to change the color of the icon which is in SVG format.But the SVG is coming as an image and hence, I'm not able to change the color of the SVG icon.

async function setFillColor(color) {
  await PowerPoint.run(async (context) => {
    const selectedShapes = context.presentation.getSelectedShapes();
    selectedShapes.load("items");
    await context.sync();

    await selectedShapes.items.forEach(async (shape) => {
      if (color != "") {
        shape.fill.setSolidColor(color);
      } else {
        shape.fill.clear();
      }
    });
  });
}


To change the color of an SVG icon in PowerPoint using Office.js, make sure to insert it as an inline shape instead of an image. Once inserted as an inline shape, you can modify properties like color in the SVG.

Your answer could be improved by explaining how to fetch/convert the SVG to an inline shape object.

Thank you for the comment. Just an FYI, I'm inserting the icon as 'XmlSvg' in the slide and after inserting if I try to change the color of this SVG Icon, then, I'm getting that SVG icon as an 'Image' and hence, I'm not able to change the color. So, i would prefer if anyone have blogs/links that can help me.
